# Pulling data from text file and setting string values equal to the data in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to pull data from a text file in the format:
    "UK,3"
    "USA,1"
    "CANADA,1"

where the Country (I.E Canada) is the name of the flag and thus it will update the background and name of the button to the correct flag and name of the country. And then the "1" corresponds to a pre-set continent.s

Basically how do I pull a line randomly and then set a string value equal to the name and a string value equal to the number?

UPDATE:

```
    // sets firstClicked and secondClicked to high value
    string firstClicked = "999";
    string secondClicked = "1000";
    string country1 = "5";
    string country2 = "1";
    string country3 = "2";
    string country4 = "3";
    string country5 = "4";
    string country6 = "1";
    string country7 = "5";
    string country8 = "4";
    string country9 = "2";
    string country10 = "5";
    string continent1 = "1";
    string continent2 = "2";
    string continent3 = "3";
    string continent4 = "4";
    string continent5 = "5";

    private void Country1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        firstClicked = country1;
        Timer.Start();

        if (Country1.Background != Brushes.Green)
        {
            if (firstClicked == secondClicked)
            {
                (new SoundPlayer(@"\Sounds\correct.wav")).Play();
                this.Country1.Background = Brushes.Green;

                // Add 1 to number (or any score you'd like)
                number = number + 10;

                // Add the new score to the label again
                score.Text = number.ToString();
            }

        }
        if (firstClicked != secondClicked)
        {
            firstClicked = "999";
            secondClicked = "1000";
            (new SoundPlayer(@"Sounds\wrong.wav")).Play();
        }

    }
```

At the moment if someone selects a flag and a country it will update a score and then highlight the country in Green.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is have a text document with country names and the corresponding continent values I.E. between 1 and 5 and then for the code to randomly pick a line and thus the buttons will be random countries every time. (continents can stay the same ofcourse)

Comment: Please show some code. We'll not code for you. We'll just help you out :)

Comment: Okay I'll explain it more with code.

Comment: I've updated the original post to show some code. I have tried to start using StreamReader but I've gotten nowhere with it. I'm a mechanical engineering student so I'm new to programming unfortunately.

Comment: maybe the [information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx) will help you read the text from the file.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at that before unfortunately it doesn't explain how to set a string as the data in the text file and it doesn't explain how to separate text that is separated by a comma to two different string variables.